# InternetOpenUrl error 87

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I call [InternetOpenUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in 2 other places in my program and it works flawlessly. But the last time I call it, it fails with error 87 (the parameter is incorrect). It's odd because the parameters are exactly the same except the url.
This is my code:

```
wchar_t url[] = {'h','t','t','p','s',':','/','/','w','w','w','.','e','x','a','m','p','l','e','.','c','o','m', 0};
HINTERNET hFile = NULL;

hOpen = InternetOpenW(L"MyAgent", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (!hOpen)
    ret = EXIT_FAILURE;

DWORD dwRequestFlags = 
              INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI
            | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTH
            | INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE
            | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE;

hFile = InternetOpenUrlW(hOpen, url, NULL, NULL, dwRequestFlags, NULL);
```

Then I use GetLastError() to find out it's 87.

Comment: I'm sure it is unrelated to the problem, but why do you declare your URL string like so? What's wrong with just using a good old string literal? *Way* easier to write, and saves you from having to remember to append the NUL terminator yourself.

Comment: Because some program may detect a url in my program and flag it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Do you mean that an anti-malware program scanning the bytes of your executable might flag the URL? Sure, it might, I guess, but writing the code this way won't change anything. 99% odds the compiler is going to generate exactly the same code. There are only so many ways to represent strings inside of a binary. :-)

Comment: There's no real error checkng. The code should not compile, those are char literals. The string is bizarre. Show a MCVE.

Comment: Cody, You're kind of wrong. pestudio doesn't detect my string this way. @David Hefferman For some reason I changed some things and took off some error checking and I just realized those are char literals. I'm gonna fix that. Also I know it's weird, but I need my string this way.

Comment: No you don't. You are imagining things. An arrays of characters is just that.

Comment: Well I'm not blind. pestudio detects a url like this wchar_t* url = L"https://example.com" but not like this wchar_t url[] = {L'h',L't',L't',L'p',L's',L':',L'/',L'/',L'e',L'x',L'a',L'm',L'p',L'l',L'e',L'.',L'c',L'o',L'm', 0 }

Comment: Hmm, yeah. I am "kind of" wrong. Looking at the assembly output generated by MSVC, it does something rather different for declarations involving string literals vs. an array of character literals. With a string literal, the string is placed into the CONST segment of the binary, and then used to make the function call. Basically what you'd expect. With the array of char literals, numeric constants are in the code itself, as literals to the MOV instructions. This bloats the instruction size, but means no strings in the data section for a naïve scanner to find. (http://pastebin.com/f7B7ETJt)

Comment: The strings are easy to find even so.

Comment: I know they're easy to find, but it's still worth doing. Actually, I'll just base64 encode them. Also I've yet to get InternetOpenUrl to succeed. This is really bizarre because I am able to download two other files the exact same way. You guys have any ideas? Why would it be returning 87 even though the parameters are correct?

Comment: I'm stupid and should have tried Base64 Encoding first rather than making a bizarre string like that.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `InternetOpenUrl()` even if `InternetOpen()` fails, so `hOpen` would be invalid.  Do something like this instead:

```
hOpen = InternetOpenW(L"MyAgent", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (!hOpen)
    ret = EXIT_FAILURE;
else
{
    DWORD dwRequestFlags = 
              INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI
            | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTH
            | INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE
            | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE;

    hFile = InternetOpenUrlW(hOpen, url, NULL, NULL, dwRequestFlags, NULL);
    if (!hFile)
        ret = EXIT_FAILURE;
    else
      // and so on...
}
```

Or:

```
ret = 0;

hOpen = InternetOpenW(L"MyAgent", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (!hOpen)
    ret = EXIT_FAILURE;

if (ret == 0)
{
    DWORD dwRequestFlags = 
              INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI
            | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTH
            | INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE
            | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE;

    hFile = InternetOpenUrlW(hOpen, url, NULL, NULL, dwRequestFlags, NULL);
    if (!hFile)
        ret = EXIT_FAILURE;
}

if (ret == 0)
{
    // and so on...
}
```

Also, this line:

```
wchar_t url[] = {'h','t','t','p','s',':','/','/','w','w','w','.','e','x','a','m','p','l','e','.','c','o','m', 0};
```

Can be re-written like this instead:

```
wchar_t url[] = L"https://www.example.com";
```

Or even this (since there so no need to make a *local copy* of the literal data):

```
const wchar_t *url = L"https://www.example.com";
```

Comment: Or, the way I would write it is to assume failure by setting `ret` to `EXIT_FAILURE` at the top of the function, and then only check for success at each junction. If you get all the way through and succeed, set `ret` to `EXIT_SUCCESS` at that point. I don't know if that description in words makes sense, but I think that produces code that is much easier to follow.

Comment: @CodyGray it doesn't matter how you do it. What is important is that the next operation must not be performed if the previous operation fails. How you decide to accomplish that is mostly a matter of personal choice. Use whatever works for your code design.

Comment: I've done as you guys said. InternetOpen succeeds and InternetOpenUrl is still failing with error 87. This is really bizarre because I am able to download two other files the exact same way.